# What did Kartikeya do to get blessings from the Lords that Hanuman had met?

Tags: shiva, gods, hanuman, kartikeya

Two days ago, I saw the series "Sankat Mochan Hanuman" on Sony TV. In
that Lord Hanuman got lots of blessings from Devtas & Lord Shiva. At that time, one of the Devta told Hanuman that he was second in race to get lot of blessings
from Devtas, first was Kartikeya (son of Lord Shiva).

My question is, what did Kartikeya do to get blessings from the Devtas that Hanuman had met?

Comment: I think it could be either when Lord Kartikeya was born when Gods blessed him or it would be before/after his fight with Tarakasur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lord Kartikeya got blessings from all gods on the occasion of his appointment as commander of the army of gods to slay Tarakasura. This story is mentioned in [Mahabharata, Book 9, Shalya Parva, Section 46](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09046.htm).

> The adorable chastiser of Paka, O tiger among kings, gave unto Guha (Kartikeya) a dart for the destruction of the enemies of the gods. That dart produces a loud whiz and is adorned with many large bells. Possessed of great splendour, it seemed to blaze with light. And Indra also gave him a banner effulgent as the morning sun. Shiva gave him a large army, exceedingly fierce and armed with diverse kinds of weapons, and endued with great energy begotten of ascetic penances. Invincible and possessing all the qualities of a good army, that force was known by the name of dhananjaya. It was protected by thirty 30,000 warriors each of whom was possessed of might equal to that of Rudra himself. That force knew not how to fly from battle. Vishnu gave him a triumphal garland that enhances the might of the wearer. Uma gave him two pieces of cloth of effulgence like that of the Sun. With great pleasure Ganga gave unto Kumara a celestial water-pot, begotten of amrita, and Brihaspati gave him a sacred stick. Garuda gave him his favourite son, a peacock of beautiful feathers. Aruna gave him a cock of sharp talons. The royal Varuna gave him a snake of great energy and might. The lord Brahma gave unto that god devoted to Brahman a black deer-skin. And the Creator of all the worlds also gave him victory in all battles.
>
> Having obtained the command of the celestial forces, Skanda looked resplendent like a blazing fire of bright flames. Accompanied by those companions and the mothers, he proceeded for the destruction of the daityas, gladdening all the foremost of the gods. The terrible host of celestials, furnished with standards adorned with bells, and equipped with drums and conchs and cymbals, and armed with weapons, and decked with many banners, looked beautiful like the autumnal firmament bespangled with planets and stars.

[Vayu Purana, Chapter 72, Verses 45 & 46](http://archive.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/vayu-mahapurana/text-with-translation/vol-ii/chapter-72) also describes similar story.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16486/what-is-the-reason-behind-lord-kartikeya-holding-a-rooster-flag/16494#16494), **Chapter 10 Section 3 Upoghaatapaada of Brahmanda Purana** also have similar story.

Comment: [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16494/3500) also describes the same